# Turn acceptance rate into a link to unaccepted questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate, unaccepted-answer

Next to a user's question their acceptance rate is shown.

Why not make the text that says `91% acceptance rate` into a link to the user's unaccepted questions?

Perhaps if this was easily recognized as a link users may be more inclined to see what they haven't accepted yet and raise their rate?

Comment: Why?  Can you explain why this would be important? I'm not sure it's clear what the benefit of this would be.

Comment: If they don't pay attention to the answers to their questions, nor their accept rate to begin with, why would they even be inclined to click it?

Comment: I would give an answer but your 25% acceptance rate is too low. Seriously though I wish they would just get rid of that metric.

Comment: I started writing up an answer but to be hones I agree with @jmort253, this has no benefit at all apart from to help the accept-rate naggers. I don't like that.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - At one point I would have disagreed with you, but nowadays I find that I just try to be helpful and don't really pay attention to accept rate. In fact, just yesterday I had an SO answer get accepted. I posted the answer 16 months ago! Thus, there's no need to harass people, as they eventually figure it out.

Comment: Declined given that [accept rate is no longer shown on a usercard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Comment: interesting... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepting an answer is optional, and is dependent on whether or not the answer solved the askers problem. If it did not, the asker is not obligated to accept.

Additionally, you're worrying about a metric that really doesn't have much impact, if you think about where the majority of your reputation score comes from.

A really great, well-written and detailed answer is likely to get 4, 5, sometimes 10 upvotes. When you think about how 10 upvotes is +100 reputation, it sort of makes the accept score seem a bit negligible, being that it's a mere +15 reputation.

In short, stop focusing on getting users to click the green checkbox and instead focus on writing great content that the community will upvote. You'll find your reputation score, and the things that you can do on the site, increase much more using this strategy.

Moreover, when you focus on writing great answers, a side effect of this is that more of your answers will be organically accepted, without needing to be pushy or say anything to the asker. This frees you up to go and look for other questions to answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! Excellent answer! on a side note, I'm so embarrassed and cracking up at the fact that I never realized my acceptance rate on meta was so low!! Here I am talking about 'those people' LOL .. I guess I thought it carried over but it doesn't!

Comment: You know, I never noticed ;)